# Scala - treat separate Types implementing a common TypeClass as the same

Tags: scala, types, finagle, argonaut

I have two case classes, let's call them `case class User` & `case class Ticket`. Both of these case classes implement the operations required to be members of a the same `TypeClass`, in this case Argonaut's `EncodeJson`.

Is it possible to view these two separate types as the same without creating an empty marker type that they both extend?

```
trait Marker
case class User extends Marker
case class Ticket extends Marker
```

To make this concrete,we have two separate functions that return these case classes:

```
case class GetUser(userId: Long) extends Service[Doesn't Matter, User] {
  def apply(req: Doesn't Matter): Future[User] = {
    magical and awesome business logic 
    return Future[User]
   }
}

case class GetTicket(ticketId: Long) extends Service[Doesn't Matter, Ticket] {
  def apply(req: Doesn't Matter): Future[Ticket] = {
    magical and awesome business logic 
    return Future[Ticket]
   }
}
```

I would like to compose these two Services so that they return the same type, in this case `argonaut.Json`, but the compiler's response to an implicit conversions is "LOLNO"

```
implicit def anyToJson[A](a: A)(implicit e: EncodeJson[A]): Json = e(a)
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you've got these case classes:

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String)
case class Ticket(id: Long)
```

And these instances:

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

implicit val encodeUser: EncodeJson[User] =
  jencode2L((u: User) => (u.id, u.name))("id", "name")

implicit val encodeTicket: EncodeJson[Ticket] = jencode1L((_: Ticket).id)("id")
```

And the following services (I'm using Finagle's representation):

```
import com.twitter.finagle.Service
import com.twitter.util.Future

case class GetUser(id: Long) extends Service[String, User] {
  def apply(req: String): Future[User] = Future(User(id, req))
}

case class GetTicket(id: Long) extends Service[String, Ticket] {
  def apply(req: String): Future[Ticket] = Future(Ticket(id))
}
```

(These are nonsense but that doesn't really matter.)

Then instead of using an implicit conversion to change the return type, you can write a method to transform a service like this:

```
def toJsonService[I, O: EncodeJson](s: Service[I, O]): Service[I, Json] =
  new Service[I, Json] {
    def apply(req: I) = s(req).map(_.asJson)
  }
```

And then apply this to your other services:

```
scala> toJsonService(GetTicket(100))
res7: com.twitter.finagle.Service[String,argonaut.Json] = <function1>
```

You could also provide this functionality as a service or a filter, or if you don't mind getting a function back, you could just use `GetTicket(100).andThen(_.map(_.asJson))` directly.

The key idea is that introducing implicit conversions should be an absolute last resort, and instead you should use the type class instance directly.